# linuxdeployqt unable to deploy gstreamer libraries

Tags: gstreamer

I have build qt inbuilt project QMediaPlayer from qt examples. and then deployed using linuxdeployqt in linux-1 using below command.

$ linuxdeployqt.appimage ./player -appimage
it genetares lib folder, and plugins folder and .config file.

Now i copied all the respective above files and pasted into another linux-2 pc. (this pc doesnot have any qt installation)

on running my application in linux-2 its showing gstreamer warnings and critical errors. even though exe opened successfully.

but whenever i clicked on play button, video not playing. this is may be the reason of gstreamer error.

please help me to how to resolve

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3cje.jpg)